# SP_Configure Lanuguage doesnt Change Language

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having issues with one of the DBs on my server.

The server language is set to British English. However the database language is set to US English.

I have tried to rectify using the SP_CONFIGURE command to change the language of the DB to British English, however the result is always US English.

```
USE TEST_DB;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 23 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE with override ;
GO
Select @@LANGID, @@LANGUAGE;
Go
```

I cannot seem to see an issue as to why the code doesnt seem to be working?
Can anyone advise me on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 set language 'English'
```

OUPUT

```
Changed language setting to us_english.
```

**[SOURCE1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174398.aspx)
 [SOURCE2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190303.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

The default language is the language that is used when a connection is first created. After the connection is established, the language is only changed via [`SET LANGUAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174398.aspx).

[`@@LANGID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186266.aspx) and [`@@LANGUAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177557.aspx) will return the *current* language for the *connection* - not the *default* language for the *server*.

So, after you've changed the language, try disconnecting your connection and creating a new one.

You may also need to check the default language for the login that you're using, because that may be set differently from the server default language, and that will take precedence over the server default.